# qt textbrowser name save in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I am trying to show my 4by4 matrix in qt gui, there for I have used one text browser for each element of matrix.  Right now I am able to display matrix using switch case but I dont like this method. I want to make an array in which I can save the name of textbrowser and willing to access them using for loop. below is the my current code. please guide me how can I get what I am willing to do.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
     {
     for (j = 0; j <= 3;j++)
     {
         switch(no){

         case 1:
             ui->textBrowser_200->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 2:
             ui->textBrowser_201->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 3:
              ui->textBrowser_202->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 4:
              ui->textBrowser_203->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 5:
              ui->textBrowser_204->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 6:
              ui->textBrowser_205->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 7:
              ui->textBrowser_206->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 8:
              ui->textBrowser_207->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 9:
              ui->textBrowser_208->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 10:
              ui->textBrowser_209->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 11:
              ui->textBrowser_210->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 12:
              ui->textBrowser_211->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 13:
              ui->textBrowser_212->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 14:
              ui->textBrowser_213->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 15:
              ui->textBrowser_214->setText(text1);
             break;
         case 16:
              ui->textBrowser_215->setText(text1);
             break;

         }
         no++;

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution which will allow you to keep your current Designer ui:

Add this member variable to your own class, to have two-dimensional matrix of widget pointers:

```
std::array< std::array <QTextBrowser *, 4>, 4> mTextBrowserMatrix;
```

Then initialize it in the constructor, with 16 lines of code like this, *after* you have called `setupUi()` for the Designer ui:

```
mTextBrowserMatrix[0][0] = ui->textBrowser_200;
// repeat above for all 16 widgets.
```

And then just access them like `mTextBrowserMatrix[0][0]` etc.

You could use any container or even plain C arrays for this, above is just an example.

---

Of course you will save some repetitive copy-paste style code and have cleaner Designer design, if you just create the QTextBrowser matrix in code, instead of using Designer for it. But since you already have them, might as well stick with it for now, 16 lines of repeated code is not that horrible.

Comment: thanku for your answer, is there any way to use STL array for this ?

Comment: @nabeel Fixed the answer, had a bit of mistake there... Yes, using STL array will work just as well, it's just interal data in your class. You could also have C-style two dimensional array, and it might be justifiable in a case like this too.

Comment: could you please show me a simple code how can I use STL array?

Comment: @nabeel My STL is pretty rusty, but I edited the code to use `std::array`. Did not test if it compiles, anybody feel free to tell if it's wrong or suggest edit to the answer.

Comment: I used your code but it is giving me error missing template arguments before 'tmp'...

Comment: Ah... Well, that code had missing template argument then. Should have been `QList<QTextBrowser*> tmp;` I suppose.

Comment: thanku its working using STL..thanku very much..as I am new to STL could you please explain a bit about std::array line of your code?

Comment: That line creates an array of arrays. Outer `std::array` creates array of four inner `std::array`. Each inner `std::array` is array of 4 `QTextBrowser*` pointers.